# How can I know when imgAreaSelect is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my imgSelectArea code:

```
ias = $('#<%=imgMain.ClientID%>').imgAreaSelect({
                handles: true,
                autoHide: false,
                minChars: 0,
                autoFill: true,
                selectOnly: true,
                mustMatch: true,
                instance: true,
                onInit: function (img, selection) {
                    $("#tagBox").css('display', 'none');
                },
                onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
                    $("#tagBox").show();
                    var x1 = selection.x1;
                    var y1 = selection.y1;
                    var x2 = selection.x2;
                    var y2 = selection.y2;
                    var position = $('#<%=imgMain.ClientID%>').position();
                }
            });
```

This works fine but I want to know when imgSelectArea is closed i.e when you click on overlay area, I want to get notified. I couldn't find this in documentation.

This is the documentation link:

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#callback-functions

Has anybody got around this issue?

Comment: I've not used that plugin before but will have a go at getting it working. Can you please explain in greater detail what event you're trying to catch and if possible link an example? At first glance, it looks like you'll need to extend the module yourself

Comment: I want to catch when the imgAreaSelect is closed i.e once you drag the handles one part is light and one part is dark. Click on dark closed the imgAreaSelect. I want to be notified when that happens. I hope I am clear now. As a hack, I inspected and saw it attaches a class named "imgareaselect-outer" to show overlay on the outerpart. I used 'live' of jquery to attach it to click event and and it works better now. I get notified when imgAreaSelect is closed. But it is just a hack. Waiting for someone to post a better answer. Currently live is to the rescue.

Comment: I found a demo here... http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I haven't got a working dev environment where I am so I can't test this but...

In `jquery.imgareaselect.js` (I'm using v0.9.8) around line 421:

```
function cancelSelection() {
    $(document).unbind('mousemove', startSelection)
        .unbind('mouseup', cancelSelection);
    hide($box.add($outer));

    setSelection(selX(x1), selY(y1), selX(x1), selY(y1));

    if (!this instanceof $.imgAreaSelect) {
        options.onSelectChange(img, getSelection());
        options.onSelectEnd(img, getSelection());
    }
    /*ADD THIS LINE*/
    options.onCancelSelection(img);
}
```

Also, around line 461, add a default, empty function:

```
    ...
        onInit: function () {},
        onSelectStart: function () {},
        onSelectChange: function () {},
        onCancelSelection: function () {}, /* Add This line */
        onSelectEnd: function () {}
    }, options));
```

You should then be able to register an event handler as usual...

```
ias = $('#<%=imgMain.ClientID%>').imgAreaSelect({
                ...
                mustMatch: true,
                instance: true,
                onInit: function (img, selection) {
                    $("#tagBox").css('display', 'none');
                },
                onCancelSelection: function (img) {
                    /*Do something*/
                },
                ...
            });
```

That's about the best I can do in notepad/ie. If it's still an issue tomorrow, I'll have a go with a dev env.

Comment: Thanks BasicLife. I really appreciate your time and effort :)